# how to capture screenshot on Motorola Xoom (android)?

Tags: android, xoom

I have a Motorola Xoom tablet of Android and I am facing the problem to take the screenshots of my application for demo purposes but haven't succeeded yet... can anyone guide me? Is there any short cut key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this?

http://letmebuzz.com/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-motorola-xoom/

Comment: Please uncheck this as the accepted answer. It looks as though the link is now dead. I will remove the answer once you've done so.

Answer (score 0):

If using Eclipse:

then switch to DDMS View and select the attached device from left panel and then press Camera Icon. It'll take screen shot of your device screen...